# При x <- c(a, b, a, a, b, b) сообщает: Error: object 'a' not found (?!)

Tags: r, rstudio

`x <- c (a, b, a, a, b, b)`

> Error: object 'a' not found

Почему выдаёт ошибку?

Answer (score 4):

```
x <- c ('a','b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b')
```

`a`   - Объект

`'a'` - символ

Comment: Это не так: 
`> typeof('a')`
`[1] "character"`

Comment: Символ - это имя переменной, например, `> typeof(quote(x))`
`[1] "symbol"`

Comment: @Ogurtsov Я под символом и подразумеваю `char`. `Char` расшифровывается как символьный тип